# I need ways in which I can access images on my rpi-4 for an android app I am making

Tags: android, android-image, raspberry-pi4

So I have a directory in my RPI-4 which there are various subfolders each of which contains images related to the folder.

I am making an android app which is basiclly a wallpaper folder and I have no clue how to access those images the only method i have in my mind is converting the images to base 64 then having a postgress database to access it but it seems a hassle to convert all the image and then also maintain and update it(as the app will also have a update feature later).

So i am open to learn new stuff in order to find an effective way to solve this.

Comment: Why do you think a postgress database (on the raspberry or on your Android device?)  could help you?

Comment: @blackapps i need an organized dataset so i was thinking of creating table for each folder where each table has the image name which is numbered 1,2,3... and their base64 code.
From the android app i can access the database create list items based on the name of all the tables in the database and like each list item has its own activity with the images which is formed by decoding the code.

Comment: `postgress database (on the raspberry or on your Android device?) ` Please answer questions.

Comment: @blackapps on the rpi

Comment: And if your Android device can not `access those images` then why do you think it could access that postgress database?

Comment: because i will be able to remotely connect the database

Comment: Well ... i'm very surpised... then how would you do that with your Android app on your Android device?

Comment: @blackapps cant i authenticate using the app on startup using java and then run basic commands like show tables; and use the returned list to do the following functions. (I am not sure how it will happen yet am just thinking of ways i can achieve it rn)

Comment: I dont know what you have in mind as before authentication your Android app has to make a connecection with a server on de raspberry. Now what kind of server would you start on the raspberry that has anything to do with that postgress database?

Comment: @blackapps after doing some research i get the point you are trying to say. I was under the impression i could port forward the database through my ip so other devices could access it but that is wrong in many ways.

Comment: But the solution is much simpler. No postgress needed. Start a webserver on the raspberry. (It comes with it and supports php i'm quite shure). Make a `listpictures.php` script that lists the pictures in the camera folder. The Android app calls it with a http component: `http://192.169.0.13/listpictures.php`. The app then knows all the picture names and can download each with for instance `http://192.168.0.13/pictures/image128.jpg`.

Comment: @blackapps i did use php to host images but i was only able to create a script for a particular folder but what im aiming for is having multiple subfolders in subpages oh each page like ``http://192.168.1.1/pic/folder1/img1.jpg`` was not able to achieve that. So guess ill be learning php for now. Thanks for your input.

Comment: You will learn that quickly and tomorrow all will run!